# Multidimensional quantiles

Tags: sampling, quantiles, multidimensional-scaling

I have 1000 observations with 2 continuous variables :

> Observation ID | X | Y

Comment: This is not a forum; please use the edit feature to alter your posts.

Comment: In what sense would those five observations be "representative"? What aspect of the data are you attempting to capture?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What's the sampling frame for selecting the sample: a list? something else?  Please describe.

Comment: They are representative because these 5 points resume the structure of the data.

For the sampling methodology, I have access to the whole population and I like to only pick up 5 users in order to resume the data.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the selected observations?

Comment: One more question: what calculation suggests that n = 5 is sufficient for statistical purposes?

Comment: The goal of this selection is to contact some people in order to better understand how they consume some products.

I have to contact less than 100 people (because it cost time and money) 5 people is just an example.

The problem is I want to pickup 5 people who are representative of the whole population.

How can I do that knowing that I only have 2 continuous information about them :
- the amount spend in x-asis
- the distance to the store in y-axis
and these 2 information are not independant as you can see

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to get good estimates and decent standard errors.

First, sort by x; then systematic sampling approaches will effectively stratify by x and by y.

- Take a single systematic sample of n observations, where n is a multiple of 2. To estimate standard errors, "stratify" the sample, with each stratum consisting of two neighboring observations: So stratum 1 is observations 1 & 2; stratum 2 is observations 3 & 4; and so on. There will be H = n/2 strata, and will provide H-1 d.f. for standard errors. This is estimator v3 on page 300 in Wolter (2007). For examples of taking systematic samples see Kish (1965, p. 113). If N/n is not an integer, the last stratum might have 3 members.

I don't recommend this approach if you expect much non-response, because survey programs like Stata will complain if you have strata with < 2 observations. To correct this, you will have to merge neighboring strata by hand. Also this commits you to a specific sample size in advance, which might turn out to be something of a burden.

- Take, say, m = 4 or 5 *independent* systematic samples in x order, each of size n/m. In the analysis, treat each sample as a cluster. This is the method of replicated subsamples. See Deming, 1960, for many examples.

This design has two advantages: First, it provides decent estimates of standard errors, although albeit with lower degrees of freedom. Second, it can adapt to your situation: Consider the first sample as a pilot test. You'll get some preliminary data, test different approaches, and get an idea of the effort needed to get completed interviews. Then do as many additional subsamples as you can afford, but *complete* the ones you start and devote effort to reducing non-response in those subsamples.

References:

Deming, W. Edwards. 1960. Sample design in business research. New York: Wiley.Wolter, Kirk M. 2007. Introduction to variance estimation. New York: Springer.

Kish, Leslie. 1965. Survey sampling. New York: Wiley.

Wolter, Kirk M. 2007. Introduction to variance estimation. New York: Springer.